# Error loading shared library libresolv.so.2 : No such file or directory (needed by /lib/libclntsh.so)

Tags: oracle, docker

I get this Error everytime i try to connect to the Oracle DB:

```
DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "Error loading shared library libnsl.so.1: N
o such file or directory (needed by /lib/libclntsh.so)". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for help
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with ldconfig.
If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html
```

And in my Dockerfile i have this code in it:

```
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib
RUN curl -OL https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19600/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    cp -r instantclient_19_6/* /lib && \
    rm -rf instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    apk add --no-cache libaio && \
    apk add --no-cache libaio libnsl libc6-compat && \
    cd /lib && \
    # Linking ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 to the lib/ location (Update accordingly)
    ln -s /lib64/* /lib && \
    ln -s libnsl.so.2 /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1 && \
    ln -s libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2
```

What am i doing wrong? I also tried `ln -s libc.so /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2`
It seems, it can't find libresolv.so.2

Comment: Are you running on an Alpine base image?  This is a class of "system libraries aren't quite right" problem that could be resolved by switching to a Debian or Ubuntu base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem

```
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh && \
    mkdir /opt/oracle && \
    cd /opt/oracle && \
    curl -OL https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19600/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    rm -rf instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    cd /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6 && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/libnsl.so.2 /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1 && \
    ln -s /lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2 && \
    apk add --no-cache libaio libnsl libc6-compat && \
    echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6:/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> /etc/profile.d/oracle_client.sh && \
    echo "export PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6:$PATH" >> /etc/profile.d/oracle_client.sh
```

Comment: Resource & tips (i) use a recent version of IC (currently 19.10).  Or use 21c - which doesn't need libnsl. (ii) Follow the [IC install instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst) and use `ldconfig` instead of setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH (iii) Review [Oracle's Dockerfiles](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleInstantClient) (iv) Review the post [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1).

Comment: @ChristopherJones ldconfig doesn't work on Alpine

Comment: I follow your script and i get `Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_6/libclntsh.so.19.1)`  - any ideas?

Comment: apk add gcompat ?

Answer (score 6):

Add gcompat in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add gcompat
```

gcompat include libresolv.so.2. See the link https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=libresolv.so.2&path=&name=&branch=edge

Comment: Also to everyone reading this answer: just a friendly reminder to update your alpine image version every once in a while